Assigning an existing site to an organization in liferay 7.3.5?
I was wondering if it would be possible to update a site or an organization to assign the organization an existing site?
So to explain, i have a user organization and i have a site, Instead of creating a new organization site with a template, i'd like to "assign" the existing site to the organization.
It's not possible in the liferay menu as far as i can tell, so i tried to make a java module to select an organization and update it, by adding the group to it. But i couldn't make that work. I also haven't found a way to update a site to somehow make it an organization site.
I tried this for example:
long orgId = ParamUtil.getLong(request, "orgId");
long groupId = ParamUtil.getLong(request, "groupId");
        
Organization organization = OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.getOrganization(orgId);
        
organization.getGroup().setGroupId(groupId);
OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.updateOrganization(organization);

I was wondering if anyone has tried this before? Any help would be appreciated :)

Let's start with: In general, I'd advise against it. As there is implied permissions-handling, the permission-check infrastructure needs to be set up in a way that it behaves the expected way.
That being said, if you are desperate to try this way, I'd create an organization site through the UI and inspect the hell out of its setup, relationships, resource-permissions etc. and see if your approach matches that outcome.
But also, I'd consider this approach to be very risky to miss something. And whatever you miss might not surface immediately, but with any random future upgrade that finds unexpected data. It certainly sounds easier to me to migrate your content from the existing site to a separately created organization site, e.g. through ex-/import.

Yeah I assumed that would be the case... thank you for clarifying! I will simply have to manually export/import the existing site.
